# How to remove this unwanted file form Emacs

Tags: linux

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVWGg.png)there is an unwanted file ##include just.c# in my terminal

I tried using the rm ##include just.c# but its not working

How to remove this file form my directory.

Comment: i am doing this course on coursera. and this is my final assignment, I think it's an online shell

Comment: Try quotes, `rm '##include just.c#'`

Comment: sorry, its not working I have added an image as well, you can view the image. it says "No such file or directory"

Comment: IT SOMEHOW WORKED!!!! YOU SIR ARE A LEGEND!!!!

Comment: You were trying to remove two files (neither of which existed): `##include` and `just.c#`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried removing them through Emacs?  Launch `emacs` and then hit `C-x d` to launch `dired`.  Then mark the files using `m`, then `d` and `x` to expunge the files.